# Win32.Malware.Heur_Generic.A.(kcloud)

Tags: ubuntu-one, wine, malware

I recently started using ubuntu as my main OS, but I am sort of addicted to ms office so I installed PlayOnLinux to be able to use it. I also use Ubuntu one cloud service to make back up of certain files like my assignments and other personal files. but recently I started observing some strange lnk.desktop files showing on my desktop. they appear when ever I open MS word to type my projects. They point to a folder in the `/home/z3r0n/.wine/drive_c/windows/command/start.exe` folder. I copied the file that they point to and uploaded it to an online virus scanner which identified the file as a cloud malware.

```
/home/z3r0n/.wine/drive_c/windows/command/start.exe
Win32.Malware.Heur_Generic.A.(kcloud)

3f886e0ea4eb35074c4d3341e8383273b6f245823bc1ea934f47561199206040 sha256
9620af530f0400fafcf6e0b35427d9e60b71f394 sha1
fe66b5254d369c6dffe4e8055f926578 md5
```

I want to know if any of you guys have experienced something similar. I made a clean install and I am now using LibreOffice instead. I am trying to stay away from UbuntuOne Cloud and installing PlayOnLinux until I find I a valid lead.

any pointers will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely not related to Ubuntu One. It sounds like you managed to install some malware along with Word.

Comment: ok... I made a mistake by deleting the binary. I should have kept it... any way based on your suggestion, I think I know where to look

Answer (score 0):

here you have a copy, I found it few minutes ago and asked my self why word is installing:
install.optimuminstaller.com/o/clean/abiword/abiword.exe

and here you have a virustotal raport:
https://www.virustotal.com/file/1d3ac5615d33cbe5a2529b2b575343fb387e7fcdb41aeebd25e65c16da94b010/analysis/1350566753/

if You have any questions feel free to ask

cheers o/

Comment: I want to see a disassembled code I learnt it connects to a dns:port or something similar